# Missing five core module folders and one enabler

Tags: 7

In Drupal 7.36, the "Administration > Modules" page (/admin/modules) lists 44 core modules. However, the folder "...\htdocs\admin\modules\" has subfolders for 40 modules, which include those 44, except Field SQL storage, List, Number, Options, and Text, plus Profile.

In other words, there are five core modules that do not have a folder in the core modules folder and there is one core module (Profile) that is not available for enabling on the "Administration > Modules" page.

Does anyone here know why that is?

The [Profile doc page](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/profile) says to "enable in admin/build/modules". That URL on my installation just takes me to the main Administration page. So how does one actually enable this module?

Comment: Your Core Module "Profile" is disabled and you want to enable it? Have you found "Requires:" word right after the module? If yes, enable first the modules stated after the word "Requires:"  before you can enable the core module Profile.

Comment: @AlyssaGono, no, "Profile" is not disabled. It just does not appear in the list at all. See the explanation by Christoph below and my follow-up question to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field submodules are inside the field module folder:

```
./modules/field/modules/number/number.module
./modules/field/modules/list/list.module
./modules/field/modules/text/text.module
./modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module
./modules/field/modules/options/options.module
```

The D7 module overview is at `admin/modules`. `admin/build/modules` was in Drupal 6; a lot of the community docs pages are badly outdated, unfortunately.

Finally, the Profile module is deprecated in Drupal 7, and therefore hidden by default.

```
modules/profile/profile.info:

; The Profile module is deprecated, and included in Drupal 7 for legacy
; purposes only. By default, the module will be hidden from the UI unless you
; are upgrading a site that uses the Profile module to extend user profiles.
; See user_system_info_alter().
hidden = TRUE
```

It's only there to provide an upgrade path for D6 sites; it can't be enabled on a new D7 site without commenting out that line.

(The reason the module is deprecated is probably that the Fields API has taken over what it used to do, so it's obsolete.)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. However, note, I went ahead and submitted a core issue on "Profile". They responded that it is depricated and subsumed into "Users". Does that conflict with what you say about the Fields API?

Comment: It really comes to the same thing: Fields drives everything related to extensible content structures ("entities"). It's a bit of an abstraction layer. Then the other modules like Node and User declare their stuff to be entities which fields can be added to.

Comment: Thanks. Still working on sorting out fields, entities, types, etc.